# LaTeX - How to write a mathematics symbol in caption

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to put a mathematics symbols in the caption of my figure with this:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{vect_CM.png}
    \caption{Vecteur $\overrightarrow{CM}$ à un moment donné}
    \label{vect_CM}
\end{figure}
```

And LaTeX show an error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
                   \crcr 
l.76 ...$\overrightarrow{CM}$ à un moment donné}
```

Do I have to use any package to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Figure captions are considered a "movable argument" as they could end up in the List of Figures (a Table of Contents of sorts). And, such things that move end up being written to file (the `.aux`, `.toc`, `.lof`, ...) for use later on. This writing requires care so that certain fragile commands don't expand prematurely. `\protect`ion helps here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \caption{Vecteur $\protect\overrightarrow{CM}$ à un moment donné}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Surely there is an easier way? A `\captionmath` that avoids having to protect everything?

Comment: I wish there is a \captionmath - but at the moment there is no such package. I am adding this comment so others can save a few minutes of their life by not searching for this.

Comment: This is not an issue anymore. Not sure what has changed in LaTeX since this answer; either `\caption` or `\overrightarrow`, but there's no need to `\protect` it anymore.

Comment: @Werner this appears to still be a problem, at least in overleaf. Using `\approx` required `\protect` to eliminate error message. Rendering actually appeared fine but there was no List of Figures in my doc to trigger expension prematurely

Comment: @Harrydewinton: Do you have a project one can play with that replicates the issue?