# Code to print column vector doesn't work in image caption

Tags: math-mode, captions

In the below example, the `\spvec` macro generates a column vector nicely in the main body of the document, but it won't compile in the caption.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\def\spvec#1{\left(\vcenter{\halign{\hfil$##$\hfil\cr \spvecA#1;;}}\right)}
\def\spvecA#1;{\if;#1;\else #1\cr \expandafter \spvecA \fi}

\begin{document}

A $test=\spvec{1;2}$ vector.

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \textbf{IMAGE HERE}
        \caption{abc... $\spvec{1;2}$}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error is

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
                   $
l.17        \caption{abc... $\spvec{1;2}$}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186933/latex-how-to-write-a-mathematics-symbol-in-caption/186934#186934

Comment: BTW: You should use low level commands like `\def` only, if you cannot use high level commands like `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand` or `\providecommand`. In the example even using `\DeclareRobustCommand*{\spvec}[1]` instead of `\def\spvec#1` could be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

- If you don't have a list of figures, or if you don't want to have the vector show up in this list, use

  ```
  \caption[abc... entry for list of figures without \spvec]{abc... $\spvec{1;2}$}
  ```

  or leave the entry completely empty

  ```
  \caption[]{abc... $\spvec{1;2}$}
  ```
- "Protect" the command `\spvec` against being broken when moved around.

  ```
  \caption{abc... $\protect\spvec{1;2}$}
  ```

For an explanation see [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands).